# Changing Masonry columns on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, masonry

I'm trying to change the Masonry number of columns with a script in jQuery. This scripts reduce the max-width of Masonry container to force show only one column. The Script works almost fine, because I need to make double click to get my changes done. ¿Is it possible to make it with only one click?

This is my script:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true,
  gutter: 24,
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button-one').on('click', function() {
    $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true,
      gutter: 24,
    });

    $('.grid').css({'max-width': '600px'});
  });
});
```

I have a Codepen demo with all the files:

[Demo](https://codepen.io/iEbyGeek/pen/OjrMdY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this:

```
$('.button-one').on('click', function() {
  $('.grid').css({'max-width': '600px'})
            .masonry('layout');
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJvGyM). See, you don't need to reinitialize the whole plugin: just command it to relayout the existing items with existing rules, based on the new dimensions of a grid container.

The way it stands, the plugin is first called again (making all the calculations using the *existing* style of a container), and only after that you change `max-width` of a grid. The second click works ok, as dimensions are already changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just change width before grid masonry)

```
$('.grid').css({'max-width': '600px'});
$('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true,
      gutter: 24,
});
```